# How to extrat random-same rows from a matrix and a vector in R

Tags: r, sample

I would like to know the command in R that can let me to do sample by bootstrap. I have a TxN big matrix and a Tx1 vector.

I would like just to extract random row (mantaining the same position of the elements in the row, WITH REPLACEMENT) from the matrix and the vector, creating a new TxN matrix' and a new Tx1 vector', but the random t extract shoould be the same for the matrix as for the vector (if the random row is the number 5 for the matrix, i want that the random row for the vector is still the number 5)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You should be more detailed about your expected output (e.g. provide an Example). Also give us some details about what you've already tried

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I think this might be the answer, but it seems too simple.
I've created some fake data to work with.

```
TN<-matrix(1:20, 4,5)
T<-4
ind<-sample(1:T,T,replace = T)
newTN<-TN[ind,]
T1<-c(1:T)
newT1<-T1[ind]
```